# How do I define variables for the current user in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

We are using vagrant and ansible to create standard development environments. 
The ansible playbooks, vagrant files, etc. are in a git repository.

I've using [variable file separation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-file-separation) to refer to variable files in the developer's home directory for some senstitive and/or user-specific information (e.g. email address).

We use the  variables by doing a `vars_file:` as part of the playbook, but have to do it for every play.

I don't want to put it in the `group_vars/all` file because it would then be in the repository and not specific to the user.

I would rather not have a file in the  repository that is ignored because people still manage to include it and it screw everybody else up.

Is there a way of doing an equivalent of `groups/all` which can contain tasks and/or variable definitions that will automatically run whenever a playbook is run?

Comment: Have you considered using `ansible.ini` and the [`cache_plugin=yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/cache.html#using-cache-plugins), or its environment variable equivalent, to slurp up some static files? I think the downside is that any `set_fact: cacheable=yes` in the playbooks would **write** to that directory, but it could still be a net win

Answer (score 0):

> We use the variables by doing a `vars_file:` as part of the playbook, but have to do it for every play.

Nope, you can do it on playbook level. (But this might be a new thing, could have been impossible back then, I did not check.)

---

> Is there a way of doing an equivalent of groups/all which can contain tasks and/or variable definitions that will automatically run whenever a playbook is run?

Automatically run/included when?! I don't think this is possible as there would be a lot of open questions like:

- Should this be specified on the target machine or the ansible server?
- How do you specify for which user should this happen on which host?
- If there are tasks: do you want this to be executed on each playbook
  when it is run using the given user? What about tasks which specifies
  that they run as root (`become`)? What about tasks that specify a
  given user to be executed as? What about tasks that are run as root
  but creates a file with the owner matching the given user?

As there are no user scopes with variables and we don't really have a "user context" outlined (see the last questions) we are currently stuck with inclusion of variable files explicitly. Hence the below options:

---

You can keep using `vars_file` and specify a *first found* list.

```
vars_file:
  - - ~/ansible_config/vars.yml
    - <default vars file somewhere on the machine>
```

This way the ansible executor user can redefine values...

---

You can use the `--extra-vars @<filepath>` syntax to include all variables from a file, and you can have more than one of these.

---

A similar thing I do is that I include every variable from every yml file within my `GLOBAL_INPUT_DIR` (which is an environment variable that can be defined before running the bash script executing ansible-playbook or in a your bash profile or something).

```
EXTRA_ARGS=`{
    {
        find "${GLOBAL_INPUT_DIR}" -iname "*.yml";
    }\
    | while read line; do echo "--extra-vars @${line} "; done \
    | tr -d "\n"
}`
ansible-playbook $@ ${EXTRA_ARGS}
```

I usually include something like this in my doings to provide an easy way of redifining variables...

BUT: be aware that this will redefine ALL occurances of a variable name within the playbook (but this was also true with `vars_file`).